# Blazor webassembly publish to local folder failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to publish my site to a local folder so I can upload it to Github Pages. I first created the site as a Blazor Server app and that worked without errors. I then made this into a Blazor webassembly and am now getting this error:

```
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.6_0.targets(614, 5): [MSB6006] "C:\Program Files\dotnet" exited with code 1.
```

I have tried using Visual Studio, Jetbrains Rider and command prompt and all of them have returned the same error. I have tried with PWA enabled and disabled but nothing has worked. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in the last asp.net core which prevents projects from building if they are located in a folder with spaces (Program Files in your case).
Can you try moving the project to another folder (for example C:) and try again?

Comment: Thankyou! I also had to change the name of the project for it work.

Comment: Fun Fact: I had the same problem, and the problem was in space. A space inside the target folder of the publishing process. 2022, everyone! ;-)